# Why is my amazon EC2 in asian pacific region having a US ip address?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip

I recently give a free trial to amazon EC2 service, I created a free tier micro instance(AMI is windows server 2008) in the Asian Pacific(Tokyo) region, but when it's done the public DNS it provided is ec2-54-238-181-35.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com.

The corresponding IP is 54.238.181.35, which I think is in the U.S. I tried to allocate some more elastic IPs but all of them seem to have a U.S. origin.

Anyone please help explain to me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.ip2location.com/demo shows that IP as being in Tokyo, Japan.

`ap-northeast-1` *is* Japan (Amazon's first Asia-Pacific North-East datacenter), and you can't reliably determine where a global organization's IP space is actually pointing. A `traceroute` on the IP shows it passing through IPs in the right region.

Comment: @Turner IP lookups are an estimate. In many cases they will be completely wrong. It's not buggy, it's the nature of the system - an IP isn't really tied to a physical location.

Comment: @Richard Your link reports "Continent: Asia, Country: Japan, State/Region: Tokyo, City: Tokyo" now.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is registered to Amazon?

IP Address  Country Code    Location    Postal Code Coordinates ISP Organization    Domain  Metro Code
54.238.181.35   US  Seattle,
Washington,
United States,
North America   98109   47.6344,
-122.3422   Amazon Technologies Amazon.com      819