# Check if Geo-blocking is working

Tags: networking

I am trying to verify that geo-blocking is working. I'm basically looking for a list of website IPs or domain-names that are hosted outside of the United States so that I can verify that they are blocked. Anyone have a list or know where I can find one? Google and duckduckgo haven't helped.

Feel free to close this question. I'm gonna answer with an IP I found

Comment: Accept the best answer, which  may be your own.   Does not have to be immediately, may take a couple days to get more answers. https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers   Closing is different, those questions need work or can't be answered well here.  https://serverfault.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick from your favorite threat intelligence database. Select some names and IPs that geolocate to, or have ASs operated by organizations in, the geo of interest.

Check both what should definitely be allowed (domains you control, your ISPs ranges) and what probably should not be.

Note that geolocation is error prone, eventually you will find incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else sees this because they need one, I found an IP out of Japan

54.238.181.35

from the following question on ServerFault

[Why is my amazon EC2 in asian pacific region having a US ip address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/547029/why-is-my-amazon-ec2-in-asian-pacific-region-having-a-us-ip-address)